# Array of objects - how to group items by property and squash data from each of grouped items into 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-map, array-reduce

I am trying to perfom operation on array that is described in topic.
What i've done already - group by common property + map data of each item to desired format. It was achieved by using reduce + map function inside it.
Now i need final part that is going to squash each of grouped items properties into 1.
My goal is to make it work properly, ideally by extending restructuring function.

**Array to restructure**

```
const arrToRestructure = [
{
    x: "test-x1",
    y: "test-y1",
    data: [
        {id: 1, label: "label-y1-1"},
        {id: 2, label: "label-y1-2"}
    ]
},
{
    x: "test-x2",
    y: "test-y1",
    data: [
        {id: 1, label: "label-y1-3"},
        {id: 2, label: "label-y1-4"}
    ]
},
{
    x: "test-x2",
    y: "test-y2",
    data: [
        {id: 1, label: "label-y2-1"},
        {id: 2, label: "label-y2-2"}
    ]
},
]
```

**restructuring function**

```
const restructureArr = () => {
    const restructuredArr = arrToRestructure.reduce(
        (prevVal, nextVal) => ({
        ...prevVal,
        [nextVal["y"]]: [
            ...(prevVal[nextVal["y"]] || []),
            nextVal.data.map((nextVal) => nextVal.label),
        ]})
        ,[]);

    return restructuredArr;
}
```

**current output**

```
{
    "test-y1": [
        [
            "label-y1-1",
            "label-y1-2"
        ],
        [
            "label-y1-3",
            "label-y1-4"
        ]
    ],
    "test-y2": [
        [
            "label-y2-1",
            "label-y2-2"
        ]
    ]
}
```

**desired output**

```
{
    "test-y1": [
        "label-y1-1",
        "label-y1-2",
        "label-y1-3",
        "label-y1-4",
    ],
    "test-y2": [
        "label-y2-1",
        "label-y2-2"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply spread the `Array#map` result each time:

```
const restructureArr = () => {
  const restructuredArr = arrToRestructure.reduce((prevVal, nextVal) => ({
    ...prevVal,
    [nextVal["y"]]: [
      ...(prevVal[nextVal["y"]] || []),
      ...nextVal.data.map((nextVal) => nextVal.label), // fix
    ]
  }) , []);
  return restructuredArr;
}
```

Some enhancements:

```js
const restructureArr = (arrToRestructure = []) => 
  arrToRestructure.reduce((acc, { y, data = [] }) => ({
    ...acc,
    [y]: [
      ...(acc[y] || []),
      ...data.map(({ label }) => label),
    ]
  }), []);

const arrToRestructure = [
  { x: "test-x1", y: "test-y1", data: [ {id: 1, label: "label-y1-1"}, {id: 2, label: "label-y1-2"} ] },
  { x: "test-x2", y: "test-y1", data: [ {id: 1, label: "label-y1-3"}, {id: 2, label: "label-y1-4"} ] },
  { x: "test-x2", y: "test-y2", data: [ {id: 1, label: "label-y2-1"}, {id: 2, label: "label-y2-2"} ] }
];
console.log(restructureArr(arrToRestructure));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group based on `y` value using `array#reduce`. Push all the label for same `y` value using `array#forEach`.

```js
const arrToRestructure = [ { x: "test-x1", y: "test-y1", data: [ {id: 1, label: "label-y1-1"}, {id: 2, label: "label-y1-2"} ] }, { x: "test-x2", y: "test-y1", data: [ {id: 1, label: "label-y1-3"}, {id: 2, label: "label-y1-4"} ] }, { x: "test-x2", y: "test-y2", data: [ {id: 1, label: "label-y2-1"}, {id: 2, label: "label-y2-2"} ] }, ],
      result = arrToRestructure.reduce((r, {y, data}) => {
        r[y] ??= [];
        data.forEach(({label}) => r[y].push(label));
        return r;
      },{});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Upvoting your answer as it also works. Howerver i will stick with @Majed one. 
Also, big thanks for reminding me that you can actually destructure values inside reduce - so obvious, but didn't come to my mind :P

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be using `Object.entries` and `.flat()`.

```js
const obj = { "test-y1": [ [ "label-y1-1", "label-y1-2" ], [ "label-y1-3", "label-y1-4" ] ], "test-y2": [ [ "label-y2-1", "label-y2-2" ] ] }

const e = Object.entries(obj).map(el => ({[el[0]]: el[1].flat()}))

let o = Object.fromEntries(e.map(x => [Object.keys(x), Object.values(x)[0]]))

console.log(o);
```